# The stairs from the warrens- where do they lead?

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines

In the warrens #1 level, there is a spot where two doors face opposite each other. One seems to be a storage facility, the other a small office with stairs leading up to another door. Does anyone know what's beyond that door?